Я хочу скомпилировать прогу на питоне с библиотекой eel
У меня ошибка при запуске скомпилированного код с библиотекой eel.
Вот скрин ошибки:

Вот его содержимое:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import eel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Вот код main.py:
import eel
import datetime
import sys
import time
import webbrowser
from os import system
from random import choice
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from openai import OpenAI
from psutil import virtual_memory as memory
from pyowm import OWM
from translate import Translator
import google.generativeai as genai
import elevenlabs

elevenlabs.set_api_key()
username = "User"
clientID = ''
clientSecret = ''
to_lang = 'ru'
genai.configure(api_key="")
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
tolng = 'en'
tr = Translator(to_lang=to_lang)
tra = Translator(to_lang=tolng)
client = OpenAI(api_key='')

eel.init('web')


@eel.expose
def process_input(user_input):
    global response_text
    try:
        if user_input.lower() == 'Алло':
            response_text = 'Что?'

        elif user_input.lower() == "Пока":
            response_text = 'До встречи!'
            sys.exit()

        elif 'Открой youtube' in user_input.lower():
            response_text = "Уже открываю."
            url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
            webbrowser.open(url)

        elif 'Открой браузер.' in user_input.lower():
            chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
            webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("google.com")

        elif "Прочитай заметку." in user_input.lower():
            with open('todo_list.txt', 'r') as file:
                tasks = file.read()
            response_text = f"Список задач: \n{tasks}"

        elif 'Расскажи факт' in user_input.lower():
            fact_url = "https://randstuff.ru/fact/"
            response = requests.get(fact_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser').findAll('td')
            items = list(soup)
            funny_fact = items[0]
            response_text = str(funny_fact).replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '').replace('  ', ' ')

        elif 'Курс доллара' in user_input.lower():
            response_text = f'Курс доллара к Узбекским суммам: {(CurrencyRates().get_rate("USD", "UZS")): 2f}.'

        elif 'Сейчас сколько' in user_input.lower():
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            response_text = str(f"Сейчас {now.hour}" + ':' + f"{now.minute}.")

        elif 'Открой дискорд' in user_input.lower():
            system(r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe")
            system("cls")
            response_text = choice(["Открываю дискорд.", "Включаю дискорд.", "Запускаю дискорд."])

        elif 'Калькулютор' in user_input.lower():
            response_text = "Открываю калькулятор."
            system("calc")

        elif 'Ножницы' in user_input.lower():
            response_text = "Открываю ножницы."
            system("snippingtool")

        elif 'Перезагрузи компьютер' in user_input.lower():
            response_text = 'До скорых встреч!'
            time.sleep(6)
            system('shutdown /r /f /t 10 /c "Перезагрузка будет выполнена через 10 секунд"')

        elif 'Какая погода' in user_input.lower():
            place = ""
            country = ""
            country_and_place = place + ", " + country
            owm = OWM('')
            mgr = owm.weather_manager()
            observation = mgr.weather_at_place(country_and_place)
            w = observation.weather
            status = tr.translate(w.detailed_status)
            humidity = w.humidity
            temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
            response_text = f"""В городе {place} сейчас {status}.\nТемпература {round(temp)} градусов по цельсию.\n
                             Влажность составляет {humidity}%.\nСкорость ветра {w.wind()['speed']} метров в секунду."""

        elif "как" and "тебя зовут" in user_input.lower():
            response_text = "Меня зовут Ассистент."

        elif "как" and "зовут тебя" in user_input.lower():
            response_text = "Меня не зовут, я сам прихожу."

        elif "на сколько нагружен компьютер" in user_input.lower() or "На сколько нагружен компьютер" in user_input.lower():
            mem = memory()
            response_text = f'Компьютер загружен на {round(mem.percent)}%.'

        elif "На сколько нагружен компьютер" in user_input.lower() or "На сколько нагружен компьютер" in user_input.lower():
            mem = memory()
            response_text = f'Компьютер загружен на {round(mem.percent)}%.'


        else:
            try:
                if user_input == "":
                    pass
                else:
                    ens = tra.translate(user_input)
                    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
                        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
                        messages=[
                            {"role": "system",
                             "content": """Your name is DerNeX, you created by DevNexe. And user name is DevNexe, if DevNexe asks you 'who am I' or 'кто я такой' or something like that,
                                        you should answer like this: 'You are DevNexe, my creator'"""},
                            {"role": "user",
                             "content": ens}
                        ]
                    )
                    gggsx = completion.choices[0].message.content
                    response_text = tr.translate(gggsx)
            except:
                try:
                    if user_input == "":
                        pass
                    else:
                        ens = tra.translate(user_input)
                        response = model.generate_content(ens)
                        hf = response.text
                        response_text = tr.translate(hf)
                except Exception as e:
                    if user_input == "":
                        pass
                    else:
                        response_text = "Произошла ошибка попробуйте позже"
                        print(e)

        try:
            if user_input == "":
                pass
            else:
                audio = elevenlabs.generate(
                    text=response_text,
                    voice="Bill",
                    model="eleven_multilingual_v2"
                )
                elevenlabs.play(audio)
        except Exception as e:
            if user_input == "":
                pass
            else:
                print(f"Error: {e}.")
                audio = elevenlabs.generate(
                    text=response_text,
                    voice="Bill",
                    model="eleven_multilingual_v2"
                )
                elevenlabs.play(audio)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}.")
    if user_input == "":
        pass
    else:
        return "DerNeX: " + response_text


eel.start('main.html', size=(600, 800))

Вот код main.html:
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta content="dark light" name="color-scheme">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <style>
    html {
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 14.32%);
    }
    

    body{
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .mes-con {
      display: grid;
      margin-top: 50px;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 90px;
      color: hsl(0deg 0% 14.32%);
    }

    .input-container {
      display: flex;
      margin: 10px;
    }


    input[type="text"] {
      background-color: #121212;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid hsl(0deg 0% 76.53%);
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 95%;
      max-height: 90px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 14.32%);
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-color: white;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: 10px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .container {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 14.32%);
    }

    #result {
      overflow-y: auto;
      color: white;
      height: 665px;
    }

    h1 {
      color: white;
    }

    #menu {
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0.27% 10.36%);
    }

    #bar {
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0.27% 10.36%);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #menu-button {
      color: white;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #menuPanel {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 30.07%);
      z-index: 1000;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    #closeButton {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
    }

    #panelText {
      color: white;
    }

    .blur {
      filter: blur(8px);
    }

    p {
      background-color: hsl(0deg 0.27% 10.36%);
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 10px 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>DerNeX</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menuPanel">
    <img id="closeButton" onclick="toggleMenuPanel()" src="close.png">
    <h1 id="panelText">test</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="bar" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
      <svg width="24" height="24" id="menu-button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="toggleMenuPanel()">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3 8C3 7.44772 3.44772 7 4 7H20C20.5523 7 21 7.44772 21 8C21 8.55228 20.5523 9 20 9H4C3.44772 9 3 8.55228 3 8ZM3 16C3 15.4477 3.44772 15 4 15H14C14.5523 15 15 15.4477 15 16C15 16.5523 14.5523 17 14 17H4C3.44772 17 3 16.5523 3 16Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
      </svg>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="logo.png">
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mes-con">
      <div id="result"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Сообщение…" oninput="handleInput(event)">
          <button class="button" onclick="sendRequest()">
            <img src="send.png">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Function to handle user input
    function handleInput(event) {
      if (event.inputType === 'insertParagraph') {
        document.getElementById('myInput').value += '\n';
      }
    }

    // Function to send user input to Python and display the result
    async function sendRequest() {
      const userInput = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

      // Отображение ввода пользователя
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `<p>Вы: ${userInput}</p>`;

      const responseText = await eel.process_input(userInput)();

      // Отображение ответа
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `<p>${responseText}</p>`;
    }

    // Function to toggle the menu panel
    function toggleMenuPanel() {
      const menuPanel = document.getElementById('menuPanel');
      const mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
      if (menuPanel.style.transform === 'translateX(-100%)') {
        menuPanel.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
        mainContainer.classList.add('blur');
      } else {
        menuPanel.style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
        mainContainer.classList.remove('blur');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Вот команда компиляции:
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon favicon.ico main.py


Попробуйте собрать без --noconsole и посмотрите запустится ли.
